# ExecuteQuery stopped working for Sharepoint ClientContext

Tags: c#, sharepoint

About a week ago code that is used to upload files to our Sharepoint site was working. Suddenly it is not and when I run the ClientContext ExecuteQuery() method I get the following error:

'=' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'.

Here is my code:

```
using (var context = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
        {
            context.Credentials = GetSharePointCredentials();
            var web = context.Web;
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Account");
            context.ExecuteQuery();
```

There is nothing fancy going on. I really have no idea where to start. Nothing has changed. The code has not changed. I am in debug mode in Visual Studio but (a) it's also not working for those using the software in production and (b) I did actually get it to work once today while debugging, so it's an intermittent thing (if failing 99% of the time can be termed intermittent).

We're hosting Sharepoint in the cloud if that helps.

Here is the stack trace:

```
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowUnexpectedToken(String expectedToken1, String expectedToken2)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowUnexpectedToken(Int32 pos, String expectedToken1, String expectedToken2)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.HandleEntityReference(Boolean isInAttributeValue, EntityExpandType expandType, Int32& charRefEndPos)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText(Int32& startPos, Int32& endPos, Int32& outOrChars)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.FinishPartialValue()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.get_Value()
at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r)
at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r, LoadOptions o)
at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.IdcrlAuth.DoGet(String url)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.IdcrlAuth.RequestFederationProviderInfo(String domainname)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.IdcrlAuth.GetFederationProviderInfo(String domainname)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.IdcrlAuth.InitFederationProviderInfoForUser(String username)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.IdcrlAuth.GetServiceToken(String username, String password, String serviceTarget, String servicePolicy)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.SharePointOnlineAuthenticationProvider.GetAuthenticationCookie(Uri url, String username, SecureString password, Boolean alwaysThrowOnFailure, EventHandler`1 executingWebRequest)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials.GetAuthenticationCookie(Uri url, Boolean refresh, Boolean alwaysThrowOnFailure)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.SetupRequestCredential(ClientRuntimeContext context, HttpWebRequest request)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.GetRequestStream()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.GetFormDigestInfoPrivate()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.EnsureFormDigest()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
at vas.Dynamics.Crm.Library.CrmGateway.SaveFileToSharePoint(String siteUrl, String relativeUrl, String documentUrl, Byte[] documentData) in C:\Users\rmorgan\Source\Repos\backoffice\VAS.Dynamics.Crm.Library\VAS.Dynamics.Crm.Library\CrmGateway.cs:line 430
at vas.Dynamics.Crm.Library.CrmGateway.SaveDocument(Guid accountId, String documentName, Byte[] documentData) in C:\Users\rmorgan\Source\Repos\backoffice\VAS.Dynamics.Crm.Library\VAS.Dynamics.Crm.Library\CrmGateway.cs:line 233
at PrintEmailContractRenewal.Form1.CreatePdfDocuments(EntityCollection contractRenewals) in C:\Users\rmorgan\Source\Repos\backoffice\PrintEmailContractRenewal\PrintEmailContractRenewal\Form1.cs:line 190
```

Comment: Please provide a stack trace?

Comment: Added it above. It's some XML error, line 1 position 107. But what XML?

Comment: How are you saving your files to SharePoint? The error states that there is an illegal character in XML, most likely the & and need to be encoded to &amps;

Comment: Saving as a byte[] array. I am not using XML. And the thing is the code fails before I even upload it. It's these lines of code:

    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Account");
    context.ExecuteQuery();

Comment: And the code has not changed. At all. Last week it worked no problem.

Comment: "Please try to check the account you try to connect the SPO has provisioned,synchronized and assigned the license to Office 365 and uses the correct password/user name." this topic might help: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/538ab361-1a91-435b-9910-66e4915169e0/error-while-connecting-office-365sharepoint-online?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Answer (score 1):

User [Doug Ware](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/doug%20ware/?ws=usercard-mini) offered:

> The cause is that some ISP's "helpfully" hijack DNS. If you are on
>   AT&T go here to opt out:
>   http://www.att.net/dnserrorassist/about/srchTrm=Redirect%20Bin

As found here in the original answer:
 https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/43525104-ee85-438a-8531-a6c461fd08f1/clientcontextexecutequery-an-unhandled-exception-of-type-systemxmlxmlexception-occurred-in?forum=sharepointdevelopment